# is there a way to make my code non case sensitive

Tags: node.js, discord.js, fs

I'm trying to make a bot able to read an input automatically, no need for a command and then check the input against a list of defined words. I have managed to get this working but i'm having trouble in such a way that if anything varies from the word on the list, the bot ignores it. Code is as follows, all help is appreciated:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    for (i = 0; i < blacklist.length; i++)
    {
      //var check = blacklist[i].trim();
      if (blacklist[i].trim().length > 0){
        var lookup = '\\b'+blacklist[i]+'\\b';
        var re = new RegExp(lookup);
        var foundpos = message.content.search(re)
    if(foundpos >=0) {
      message.delete();
      break;
  }}}
  for(i in blacklist) {
    console.log(blacklist[i]);
  }  
})
```

Comment: Try `var re = new RegExp(lookup, 'i');`

Comment: thank you so much, you just saved me a headache